# `[FromQuery]` IEnumerable<SomeObject> parsing in ASP.NET Core 3.1?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, model-view-controller, model-binding, model-validation

So, when I tested how binding works for an `IEnumerable<string>` argument, you simply pass the argument's name in the query string, repeatedly, like this: `?a=item1&a=item2&a=item3...`

So, what must I write, if I have an argument of type `IEnumerable<SimpleObject> a`, where `SimpleObject` is defined as the following:

```
public class SimpleObject
{
   public string Number { get; set; }
   public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

in order to successfully bind it to a list of said objects? Or no such default ModelBinder exists for that mapping? *(Please provide a sample ModelBinder in that case)*

Comment: Don't you want to use another method with GET? You can pass you parameters as json string with header, and then parse it into model.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The default model-binding setup supports an indexed format, where each property is specified against an index. This is best demonstrated with an example query-string:

```
?a[0].Number=1&a[0].Text=item1&a[1].Number=2&a[1].Text=item2
```

As shown, this sets the following key-value pairs

- `a[0].Number` = `1`
- `a[0].Text` = `item1`
- `a[1].Number` = `2`
- `a[2].Text` = `item2`

This isn't quite covered in the official docs, but there's a section on [collections](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding#collections) and one on [dictionaries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding#dictionaries). The approach shown above is a combination of these approaches.